# Metric functions for 3D Euclidean space using an alternate coordinate system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am trying to find the metric functions $g_{ab}'(x')$ for a coordinate system $x'^a$ used to decribe the 3D Euclidean space. The coordinate system $x'^a$ is related to the Cartesian coordinates $x^a$ by
$$x^1=x'^1+x'^2$$ $$x^2=x'^1-x'^2$$ $$x^3=2x'^1x'^2+x'^3$$

To find the metric functions $g'_{ab}(x')$, I started with the line element for the Cartesian coordinate system $$ds^2=(dx^1)^2+(dx^2)^2+(dx^3)^2$$

I substituted the differential equations for $dx^1$, $dx^2$ and $dx^3$ into the above line element to get
$$ds^2=[2+4(x'^2)^2](dx'^1)^2 +[2+4(x'^1)^2](dx'^2)^2+(dx'^3)^2+8x'^2x'^1dx'^1dx'^2+4x'^2dx'^1dx'^3 +4x'^1dx'^2dx'^3$$
i.e. the line element in terms of the coordinate system $x'^a$.

I compared this to the general expression for the line element in Riemanniam manifolds
$$ds^2=g_{ab}(x)dx^adx^b$$

and realised that in my previously obtained expression for $ds^2$, terms like $g_{12}(x')dx'^1dx'^2+g_{21}(x')dx'^2dx'^1 $ are grouped into a single term which is $8x'^2x'^1dx'^1dx'^2$.

Is there a rule that states how I should distribute the $8x'^2x'^1$ term between the metric functions $g_{12}(x')$ and $g_{21}(x')$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: the metric is symmetric. $g_{12}$ and $g_{21}$ are equal, and each is equal to half the coefficient of $dx^1 dx^2$ in $ds^2$. In your example, to be extra clear you could write the relevant part of the metric as

$$8 x^1 x^2 dx^1 dx^2 = 4 x^1 x^2 dx^1 dx^2 + 4 x^1 x^2 dx^2 dx^1 = g_{12} dx^1 dx^2 + g_{21} dx^2 dx^1.$$

But we normally write just one combined term, because we know that the metric is symmetric.

---

So why is the metric symmetric? There are sort of two perspectives, which are of course equivalent in the end. If your definition of the metric is that distances are measured by $ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}\, dx^\mu dx^\nu$, then as you noted there is an ambiguity: there are infinitely many ways to split the coefficient of the $dx^1 dx^2$ term into $g_{12}$ and $g_{21}$. In this case, we decide to make the metric symmetric just to have *some* convention, and that's of course the simplest one. It also has the important property that it is preserved under coordinate transformations.

The other definition is that the metric is a function giving the inner product of two vectors as $\mathbf{U} \cdot \mathbf{V} = g(\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{V}) = g_{\mu\nu} U^\mu V^\nu$. In this case, the metric is symmetric because that's just part of the definition of an inner product. We *could* consider nonsymmetric products, but as far as I know that doesn't lead to any interesting geometric theory. Symmetric inner products have worked well for us so far.

Comment: As an additional question, why is the metric required to be symmetric?

Comment: @TaeNyFan See my edit.